# Get the id of an option chosen in a select by a user

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tryin to get the id of an option chosen in a select by a user.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    $(".my_select_class").change(function(){
        var d = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');
        alert(d);

        return false;       
    });
});
```

The id exists cause I display it in my php code but the alert open a white frame without any character, I don't understand why. Maybe because "attr('id')" doesn't work with "find('option:selected')" ?

Comment: This should work as expected. Do your `<option>` elements actually have `id` attributes (e.g. `<option id="option-foo" value="foo">Foo</option>`), or are you after their `value` attributes instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code just works for me. see http://jsfiddle.net/QhXwT/

Comment: where is it say that the atttr is not supported in 1.7 ?